# "+:", ":" means before function name in c++

Tags: c++, function, class

in header file:

```
 class ClassName {
    public:
        ClassName(int unitID, int ctrlPin);
        ClassName(Stream &serial, int unitID, int ctrlPin);


    private:
        Stream &serial;
    };
```

in cpp file:

```
ClassName::ClassName(int unitID, int ctrlPin)
:ClassName(Serial, unitID, ctrlPin)
{}

Modbus::Modbus(Stream &_serial, int unitID, int ctrlPin)
+:serial(_serial)
{
    // set modbus slave unit id
    unitID = _unitID;

    // set control pin for 485 write.
    ctrlPin = _ctrlPin;
}
```

`serial()` is an external function.
What does `:` mean in `:ClassName` and `+:` in `+:serial`?

Comment: Nothing, this is no valid syntax. It likely resulted from copying some git diff output.

Comment: ok +: is not true, I corrected

Comment: But what about ":" ?

Comment: Regarding `:ClassName(Serial, ...` see ["Delegating Constructor"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

':' is to mark the beginning of the **initializer** list. It is used in the constructor of the class.

Check this [link](https://www.quora.com/In-C++-what-is-an-initializer-list) for an explanation of the initializer list.

---

'+:' is *not* valid syntax.

Comment: What does "initializer list" mean?

Comment: @Ahrovan A list of initiations with the member variables to set their initial value

Comment: and for `ClassName` you not merely initialize members but call an other version constructor with `:`